# How to implement generic method in c#

Tags: c#

Please may i have help on implementing generic methods. I am getting this message:

> Error  1   'T' does not contain a definition for 'GetDetails' and no extension method 'GetDetails' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference)

Where am i getting it wrong?

```
public static void displayAnimal<T>(ref T mammal)
{
    T ourMammal;
    ourMammal =  mammal;
    mammal.GetDetails();
}
```

Comment: What would you expect to happen if I wrote: `string x = "foo"; displayAnimal(ref foo);`? It's also unclear why you have a ref parameter at all.

Comment: sorry @jon i am not good at programming, what  wanted to do is if you give foo as you did, i would expect foo to be an animal then to get the number of legs and sounds that foo will be assigned

Comment: But it's not an animal - it's just a string... and there's nothing in your method signature to stop that call. Why are you using generics here at all? I suspect you're making your life much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @JonSkeet I think he need something like -  DisplayAnimal<T>(T mammal) where T : Mammal   - but I'm also not sure :-) so we have to wait for the clarification?

Comment: T is an otherwise unspecified type and won't know how to .GetDetails() on its own. You'll need to implement an interface or inherit from a base class then restrict T to one of those, if you wish to be able to invoke that method off your generic type.

Comment: @BassamAlugili: But nothing shown requires it to be generic. Just `DisplayAnimal(Mammal mammal)` would be fine. That's why I'm asking why the OP is using a `ref` parameter, and why they're using generics.

Comment: @JonSkeet the use of genetics here appears to be academic - no real purpose other than to demonstrate its use. I agree that the ref parameter has no purpose at all.

Comment: @S.Brentson: Well, that's a guess. Maybe the OP really thought they needed generics. Only the OP can say, which is why I was asking.

Comment: @BassamAlugili indeed i was making life difficult, i want to grasp some of the concepts of c# so i was playing around with examples of code, what i wanted to do was to be able to use the method for any type of object that i create

Comment: after adding a constraint the error disappeared. Thank you guys for the help and insight

Comment: and I also did away with the ref also does not change anythin

Answer (score 4):

Since T can be any type and compiler doesn't know what type this method would get , it's possible to use only general object methods. If you need to use method of some class or interface you should specify 'where'(generic type constraint)

```
  interface IAnimal // or class 
        {
         /*return type*/ GetDetails();
        }

        public static void displayAnimal<T>(ref T mammal) where T :IAnimal
            {
                T ourMammal;
                ourMammal =  mammal;
                mammal.GetDetails();
            }
```

Comment: While i was writing this René Vogt already write the same and even better answer)

Answer (score 2):

Your method is generic, so the compiler does not know (at compile time) which *specific* type `T` will be. Imagine I would call that method like

```
int noGetDetails = 12;
displayAnimal(ref noGetDetails);
```

`int` does not have an `GetDetails()` implementation.

So there is no way for the compiler to determine what `mammal.GetDetails()` could be, since there is no type defined for `mammal`.

You can add *generic constraints* to enforce `T` being a type that implements a `GetDetails()` method:

```
public class MammalBase
{
    public void GetDetails() { return... }
}

public class YourClass
{
    public static void displayAnimal<T>(ref T mammal) where T : MammalBase // this is the constraint
    {
        mammal.GetDetails();
    }
}
```

The constraint `where T : MammalBase` tells the compiler that only types inherited from `MammalBase` can be used as generic arguments. So the compiler knows that `mammal` implements a `GetDetails()` method.

---

*Note* that there is no use for the `ref` keyword in your code, and that you actually don't need generics for the code shown since you can simply make your parameter type `MammalBase` (but maybe you just showed a shortened example and need `ref` and generics for your real application).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of possible types that you intend to use it would also be possible to try to cast the generic type and check whether it worked.

```
public static void displayAnimal<T>(T mammal)
{
    TargetType targetMammal = T as TargetType;

    if(targetMammal != null)
    {
        // the target type should have the function .GetDetails();
        targetMammal.GetDetails();
    }
}
```

if you cast it intellisense will tell you which properties and functions you can access.